# Can strace/ptrace cause a program to crash?

Tags: strace

So recently, I was discussing strace with somebody, and they were asking what would happen if you straced a running process just as it was creating a network socket or something similar. Could this cause the program to crash in unexpected ways?

From what I've read about ptrace, the syscall used by strace, it shouldn't be able to cause anything like that if you're just debugging a thread. The process gets stopped, every time a syscall is called, but it should later resume and be none the wiser. Signals get queued while it's not running, so I assume something similar happens with syscalls/sockets/listen.

Can ptrace used in the context of strace cause any weird process crashes?

Comment: There was a time with ancient kernels that had bugs, where detaching from a process made it "disappear" (getting SIGKILL). This doesn't happen anymore for many years now, but maybe you read about some myths that are still around. Note that with ptrace you have the ability to write to the process memory, but strace doesnt use any ptrace calls for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**, `strace` should not cause a program crash -

**Except** in this somewhat unusual case:

If it has a bug that depends on **timing of execution**, or runtime **memory locations**.

It may trigger this kind of "**heisenbug**" - but extremely rarely, because this kind of bug is rare, and it needs to only trigger under strace or other instrumentation.
And when you find a heisenbug, that's often a good thing.

Regarding `ptrace()` - the syscall - that is just what `strace` does inside I think, so it's similar. One can just do more than `strace` can when using `ptrace()` directly.

Your example would be just this kind of bug:

In the example, `strace` would change the timing of the steps to create a network connection. If that causes a problem, it was a "problem waiting to happen" - the timing of execution changes constantly. With `strace`, just a little more. But any other application could have changed the timing more, like starting a program.

Comment: +1 To clarify WRT sockets, it wouldn't be the actual establishment of a connection that would trigger such a bug.  I can't really imagine anyone writing general purpose networking code that was timing critical in this sense, although it's obviously possible.  I'm curious as to what you mean by the "runtime memory locations" complication.

Comment: Oh, true, the network code would be from well tested libs. Regarding the memory, I "just assumed" that the instrumentation with strace somehow changes the memory use or the process, such that null pointers point elsewhere now. Hmmm... if the `strace` instrumentation happens fully outside the traced process, that may be wrong. ('ltrace' should be in the process, changing library call addresses)

Comment: Exactly the information I was looking for, thanks! So basically, in a well written application, strace/ptrace shouldn't cause issues. Issues that arise while using strace/ptrace may be trigger by other things as well (such as slower computers). I don't think ptrace modifies memory locations, but I'll have to check.

Comment: `strace` only uses eavesdropping features of `ptrace`. `ptrace` can also modify the execution of a program, and if you do that, it's very easy to cause the program to crash.

Comment: Interesting - I expected at least "possible to crash" - but it seemed to me the OP did not ask for use independant of `strace`, in the last line he wrote explicitly "ptrace used in the context of strace".

Answer (score 3):

> what would happen if you straced a running process just as it was creating a network socket or something similar.

Stuff like that is done via [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), meaning the process makes a request of the kernel, and the kernel fulfils it.  The kernel also does the magic to make `ptrace()` work.  While this doesn't mean it would be impossible for it to trip over itself (which would be a bug), it seems unlikely as this is explicitly one of its purposes: to coordinate processes on a multitasking system.

Answer (score 1):

I find that stracing GUI processes often leads to crashes, even on recent OS (OpenSuse 12.3 at least, I haven't specifically tried on 13.1 as I have pretty much given up on stracing GUI processes).

I can't recall seeing stracing of a non-GUI process lead to crashes on any recent OS.

Comment: I could see how maybe tracing a GUI program from a terminal running under the same GUI (same X11 display) could trigger a deadlock of some kind, but tracing a GUI program from elsewhere, or tracing it with the trace output redirected to a file shouldn't be able to cause that.

Comment: GUI programs often have a lot of race conditions in them due to sloppy coding. This causes crashes. For example, the program might be sending several commands to X and expecting them to all be complete in another thread or signal handler. They get back an unexpected value and don't know what to do.

Comment: For the record, I have the same problem with some GUI programs and I traced it down to NVidia's proprietary CUDA library terminating the process if its (SUID) `nvidia-modprobe` helper fails. Since `strace` ptraces it, its suid doesn't work so it fails and the CUDA library terminates the program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's rare, and I don't have a good idea why, but it definitely happens. Recently I had this happen to me tracing a long-running "swapoff" command and there was no network access nor anything else that looked like it would/should cause a problem. Nonetheless, shortly after strace was attached the process exited.

```
>strace -p 73358
strace: Process 73358 attached
getuid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getgid()                                = 0
getegid()                               = 0
prctl(PR_GET_DUMPABLE)                  = 1
stat("/etc/fstab", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2168, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/fstab", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2168, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f24e5cd8000
read(3, "\n#\n# /etc/fstab\n# Created by ana"..., 4096) = 2168
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f24e5cd8000, 4096)            = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(-1)                          = ?
+++ exited with 255 +++
```

It looks like the process decided to voluntarily exit, but considering that it had run for several hours before the strace was started, I doubt that this exit was coincidence.

So yes, strace can sometimes cause the process to abort, but it's rare enough that the benefits of getting good info can outweigh that risk.

Another option on linux would be to check `/proc/<PID>/stack` to see where the process is currently blocked. This is safer, but provides less dynamic information.